# codeigniter 4 how to make menu bar links

Tags: codeigniter, url, codeigniter-4, url-helper

I am a beginner at CodeIgniter. I want to know how to link one page to another. I tried to like this. I got the error
404 - File Not Found
Sorry! I cannot seem to find the page you were looking for.

What I tried so far I attached below.
**view page:-**

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('aboutus') ?>">Aboutus</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('contactus') ?>">Contactus</a></li>
```

Controller Page

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }

    public function aboutus()
    {
        return view('about');
    }

    public function contactus()
    {
        return view('contact');
    }
```

when the page is loaded, called in the index page index, I made the links about I had a problem

What is wrong here.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/index.php/home/aboutus   linkes home like this

Comment: <?php echo site_url           i  used this for moving another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing a very important thing, the name of your controller.

Lets say your have a controller called site and all those functions are in it. In that case your code should look like this:

```
class site extends CI_Controller{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }

    public function aboutus()
    {
        return view('about');
    }

    public function contactus()
    {
        return view('contact');
    }

}
```

Then all your links should look like this:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('site/aboutus') ?>">Aboutus</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('site/contactus') ?>">Contactus</a></li>
```

In case you want to remove controller name from your urls your need to look into the routing features codeigniter offers.

Comment: ya.sir. my controller name is home. <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('home/aboutus') ?>">Aboutus</a></li> now it  is working but url look like http://localhost:8080/index.php/home/aboutus

Comment: $routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->add('aboutus', 'App\Controllers\Home::aboutus');
$routes->add('contactus', 'App\Controllers\Home::contactus');
what is wrong

Comment: @haridran That really depends, I don't know if OP is using ci3 or 4. Since there's no info about it. I left that out because of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('controller/function')?>"></a>
or
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function')?>"></a>
```

**Then Change Your Links as:-**

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/aboutus') ?>">Aboutus</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/contactus') ?>">Contactus</a></li>
```

Comment: this->load->helper('url'); i added my got the error.  'url'  inside here which url have to put

Comment: @hari dran in `marcogmonteiro` answer you solved  but you have to remove only index.php from that.

Comment: $this->load->helper() is not valid in CodeIgniter 4. Use helper() instead. Also, URL helper is automatically loaded by the system so you don't have to load it yourself.

Comment: $routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->add('aboutus', 'App\Controllers\Home::aboutus');
$routes->add('contactus', 'App\Controllers\Home::contactus');
what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the routes. Open `Routes.php` file under application configuration and register routes to access your controller methods.

Example

```
$routes->add('aboutus', 'App\Controllers\TheClassName::aboutus');
```

Change *TheClassName* to the name of class where *aboutus* method is

Comment: i changed but still output url look like this  localhost:8080/index.php/home/aboutus . i need to remove index.php

Comment: $routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->add('aboutus', 'App\Controllers\Home::aboutus');
$routes->add('contactus', 'App\Controllers\Home::contactus');
what is wrong

Comment: Open App.php under Config folder and set indexPage = '';

Comment: With the above route, you need to access the page like this localhost:8080/aboutus